# Як можна/потрібно запрошувати нових людей під час приватної бети? / Should we invite new people during private beta?

Tags: discussion

Учасникам приватної бети доступна опція "запросити експертів" (Invite Fellow Experts) через електронну пошту. Яку максимальну кількість запрошень можна відправити і чи є це прийнятним?

During private beta, we can invite fellow experts via email. How many experts can we invite? Is it acceptable during private beta?

Answer (score 4):

Я бачив цю форму, але ніколи нею не користувався.

Під час приватної бети я намагаюся запрошувати людей так само (фейсбук, особисті контекти тощо), як і до неї. Адже щоби зайти на сайт під час приватної бети, не треба бути комітером чи спеціально запрошеним. Просто заходиш на [сторінку пропозиції](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language) і натискаєш «Visit!» (хоча за <s>[прямим посиланням](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/)</s>, доки хоч раз не клікнув «Visit!», зайти не можна). <sub>Наприклад:</sub>

- <sub>я ніяк не пов'язаний з «Vegetarianism», що зараз в приватній беті;</sub>
- <sub>я не міг зайти до нього за <s>[прямим посиланням](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/)</s> (писалося щось типу «вибачте, сайт зараз в приватній беті, без запрошення — зась!»);</sub>
- <sub>зайшовши до нього на [сторінку пропозиції](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94068/vegetarianism), клацнувши «Visit!» і погодившись з чимось на зразок «так, я розумію, що це приватна бета, я буду акуратний, щоби їм там не напартачити), я потрапив туду, отримав змогу стати учасником і заходити (навіть без commit-них обіцянок).</sub>

<sub>Причому, судячи з повідомлень на загальній ме́ті (чи меті Ареа 51, вже не пам'ятаю) — це не security breach, а просто feature.</sub> Відповідно, раз люди можуть під час приватної бети заходити необмежено — то, напевно, і використання цієї форми не обмежено ніяк технічно чи морально.

Питання в тому, що *нам самим потрібно*. (Чи потрібно нам запрошувати нових людей, яких саме — лише спеціалістів, лише обізнаних на SE, чи всіх — і т.д.)

Comment: А можливість питати і відповідати у вас там з'явилася?

Comment: @AlexSodin, так, звісно. Ну, я, правда, не питав нічого на вегетаріанстві, але дойшов до форм питання і відповіді. Навряд чи воно не дасть відправити в самий останній момент.

Comment: Ну тоді чому б не запрошувати нових людей? Навряд вони будуть менш відповідальними, ніж ті, хто відгукнувся раніше.

Comment: @AlexSodin, ну я й запрошую :) (якщо спадає нагода). Я просто хотів сказати — ця форма не обмежує нас в кількості запрошених, це цілковито наша справа (хочемо запрошувати — запрошуємо, не хочемо — не запрошуємо).